# How can I easily preview my illustrator document on my iPad?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, ipad

I am designing screens for an app for iPad. I would like to easily preview my artboards on my iPad.

My method to do that is:

- export the `.ai` document to a `.pdf` document
- copy the `.pdf` file to my "books" in iTunes
- then, open this new `.pdf` file with the books app on my iPad

**Is there a more clever way than what I an doing right now?**

---

EDIT: The resason I want to preview is to compare 2 ou more screens. A good point in the process I use in that with a swipe I can compare two artboards.

Comment: The drop box app can preview .ai files. It's just a rasterized preview, but as long as you don't zoom in, it should be fine.

Comment: Sneak Peek in the app store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sneakpeek/id398347349?mt=8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skala is a great free app that mirrors your screen on to mobile devices. It can link directly to photoshop and also send over JPGs and clipboard.

Skala: http://bjango.com/mac/skalapreview/

Comment: Does Skala work with Illustrator too? I thought it is only for Photoshop …

Comment: No, it is not very compatible. For instance, I have tested it, and my .ai file has several art boards but only the first one is previewed...

Comment: BUT, it is very handy to design one screen! I like it! When I save, it automatically updates the image displayed in the iPad! Great!

Comment: Yes, Skala Preview can send AI and PDF files, but just the first artboard or page. However, you can reorder the artboards in Illustrator to send any artboard.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using an app called [iDraw](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fidraw%2Fid363317633%3Fmt%3D8&ei=3SYxVfL8E8yxyASL7YHADw&usg=AFQjCNGBnAb5EVVqRFa6NUU6J875VsNk5g&sig2=NSd_jioyoTFbxPZc678DoA&bvm=bv.91071109,d.aWw) from the app store. It let's me open .AI files directly on my iPad and I can connect it to my dropbox. So I save the file on my computer in my dropbox and then I can easily open it on my iPad almost immediately.

Here's a couple screenshots of the iDraw app:

[image: screenshot-01]

[image: screenshot-02]

Also, you may want to try this app called [Astropad.](http://astropad.com/) It lets you use your iPad as second screen and also a drawing tablet with Illustrator. It has no lag and works great. Plus you can try it for free.

Answer (score 1):

Download iTools or similar software to manage your iPad Device albums.
Then you can **export** your work to `.jpg` and import to your device.

iTools Official Website: [www.itools.cn](http://www.itools.cn)

Answer (score 1):

I have an amazingly easy solution / tweak

1. Tap that ai file to open
2. It will open up the Share Sheet
3. Tap Print
4. Pinch to zoom that file to preview

simple!!

Or if you want to use app
Documents by Readdle allows you to preview Ai files !!

Comment: This somewhat hidden trick let’s you natively convert ai to pdf! No apps needed.

Answer (score -1):

Export the .ai document in PhotoShop as a link file
Use Adobe Preview CC to view your file directly in your iPad

Comment: Hey there WitoldW. Can you please provide a little more detail in your answer? In order to "Export the AI document from Photoshop", you have to open the AI file in Photoshop first...  are there any options that are going to pop up if the user tries to File > Open > filename.ai ? What does "export as link file" mean? It's best assume the person asking the the question (and anyone who comes across it later) is a beginner. Clear, step-by-step instructions are great!